# SQL Server Import/Export: How do I create a column delimiter EXCEPTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, import, mysqli

My column delimiter is a vertical bar "|"
How do I tell SQL to not create a new column when it sees "\|"

My text files are delimited by a vertical bar, "|".  However sometimes the vertical bar will appear in a name/value, and SQL will split this into separate columns.  To fix this issue, the owner of the data inserted an \ in front of each vertical bar which is NOT a delimiter.

What is the most seamless way to tell SQL Server to not split a field in a separate column when it sees  "\|" as opposed to a normal vertical bar.  Can I use the text qualifier/some other simple method to do this?

Comment: You should use a "text identifier" instead of that escaping char. If you have `"` as a text identifier, and wrapped the contents of the column in them (`"askljdalsjkd|klj"|kdkd|kdslsd`), then you wouldn't have a problem

Comment: Can't you use a conventional format like CSV?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a great way, SQL Server allows for text qualifiers, but not a delimiter escape, to my knowledge.

Unless there's always a space surrounding the delimiter, in which case you could use " | " (space pipe space) as your delimiter to exclude the slashpipe.

If you can't get the data in a proper format, you could replace occurrences of "/|" with a non-standard character or string, via a simple script or in SSIS.

You could also import the file as is and adjust it after import (or during import if using SSIS).  Depending on how many errant pipes there are, this may be unreasonable.